# remove libbox2d,libspin,libchipmunk from cocos2dx visual studio project

Tags: configuration, cocos2d-x

I have a cocos2d-x project that created with command line :

```
$cocos new MyGame -l cpp -p com.xxx.MyGame
```

It just a hello world project, I don't plan to use box2d or spin or chipmunk in the future, and so HOW to remove box2d/spin/bullet project from MyGame solution completely?

update:
simply remove these project cause compile error.

update:

1>libtiff-2015.lib(tif_win32.obj) : warning LNK4075: ignoring '/EDITANDCONTINUE' due to '/OPT:ICF' specification
1>     Creating library E:\code\cocos2dx\mycocos\proj.win32\Release.win32\libcocos2d.lib and object E:\code\cocos2dx\mycocos\proj.win32\Release.win32\libcocos2d.exp
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>websockets.lib(libwebsockets.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol ___iob_func imported in function _lwsl_emit_stderr
1>libtiff-2015.lib(tif_aux.obj) : warning LNK4204: 'E:\code\cocos2dx\mycocos\proj.win32\Release.win32\vc140.pdb' is missing debugging information for referencing module; linking object as if no debug info
1>libtiff-2015.lib(tif_close.obj) : warning LNK4204: 'E:\code\cocos2dx\mycocos\proj.win32\Release.win32\vc140.pdb' is missing debugging information for referencing module; linking object as if no debug info.......
1>  libcocos2d.vcxproj -> E:\code\cocos2dx\mycocos\proj.win32\Release.win32\libcocos2d.dll
2>------ Build started: Project: mycocos, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
2>     Creating library E:\code\cocos2dx\mycocos\proj.win32\Release.win32\mycocos.lib and object E:\code\cocos2dx\mycocos\proj.win32\Release.win32\mycocos.exp
2>AppDelegate.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static void __cdecl cocos2d::GLView::setGLContextAttrs(struct GLContextAttrs &)" (__imp_?setGLContextAttrs@GLView@cocos2d@@SAXAAUGLContextAttrs@@@Z)
2>AppDelegate.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall cocos2d::Rect::Rect(float,float,float,float)" (__imp_??0Rect@cocos2d@@QAE@MMMM@Z)......
2>HelloWorldScene.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall cocos2d::Vec2::~Vec2(void)" (__imp_??1Vec2@cocos2d@@QAE@XZ)
2>HelloWorldScene.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall cocos2d::Vec2::Vec2(float,float)" (__imp_??0Vec2@cocos2d@@QAE@MM@Z)
2>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static class cocos2d::Application * __cdecl cocos2d::Application::getInstance(void)" (__imp_?getInstance@Application@cocos2d@@SAPAV12@XZ)
2>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: int __thiscall cocos2d::Application::run(void)" (__imp_?run@Application@cocos2d@@QAEHXZ)
2>E:\code\cocos2dx\mycocos\proj.win32\Release.win32\mycocos.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 241 unresolved externals
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: I dont see a reason why you would you want to go through that trouble at all even if you are not using it. You can remove or modify the libraries specific to your platforms in yourproject/cocos/platform folder

Answer (score 1):

I did this the other day :)

1) Start by disabling unused features in cocos/base/ccConfig.h such as:

```
#define CC_USE_PHYSICS 0
```

2) Next remove libraries from linker options in your project properties and cocos2d-x project properties in Visual Studio. If what you want to exclude isn't here continue to step 3.

3) Finally remove libraries from cocos\2d\cocos2dx.props